# Python 2 and 3 csv reader

Tags: python, encoding, csv, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the csv module to read a utf-8 csv file, and I have some trouble to create a generic code for python 2 and 3 due to encoding.

Here is the original code in Python 2.7:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='\"')
    langs = next(csv_reader)[1:]
    for row in csv_reader:
        pass
```

But when I run it with python 3, it doesn't like the fact that I open the file without "encoding". I tried this:

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='\"')
    langs = next(csv_reader)[1:]
    for row in csv_reader:
        pass
```

Now python 2 can't decode the line in the "for" loop. So... how should I do it ?

Comment: So you want code that runs unchanged both on Python 2.7 and 3? Probably impossible, given that so much has changed with string handling etc.

Comment: is it possible to specify block code for python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: You could check `sys.version` and wrap an `if - else` statement around your code, yes.

Comment: @Tim Pietzchker; its better to ask forgiveness than permission.

Comment: I think you had the b flag in the wrong example, I switched it around.

Comment: @JakobBowyer EAFP works only in named functions, not in generator expressions. This is intentional, which I can tell because [PEP 463](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) for inline catching was rejected.

Comment: While the "official" recommendation is to do CSVs differently in Python 2 and Python 3, there is a [cleaner, more elegant way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39379062/95852) listed as an answer to a [similar, if not duplicate, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808284/portable-way-to-write-csv-file-in-python-2-or-python-3).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indeed, in Python 2 the file should be opened in binary mode, but in Python 3 in text mode. [Also in Python 3 `newline=''` should be specified](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html#module-csv) (which you forgot).

You'll have to do the file opening in an if-block.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    infile = open(filename, 'rb')
else:
    infile = open(filename, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf8')


with infile as csvfile:
    ...
```

Comment: Can you do `with` on a file handle?

Comment: @Tim: It's not a file handle, it's a file object, and you can do `with` on file objects. That's exactly what you do when you do `with open(...`.

Comment: Makes sense. You never really see it that way, it's always `with open(...)` in the docs, but this way isn't half bad - enables you to wrap the `open()` in a `try` block and catch `File not found` etc. before handing it to the `with` block.

Comment: Or, in some situations, `if sys.version < '3': open = codecs.open`.

Comment: @agf: Yeah, that can work too. codecs.open and Python 3 open are not exactly the same, though so there are subtle traps, but often it will work. In 2.6 and 2.7 you can do `from io import open`, though.

Comment: The Python 2 CSV reader only works with ASCII, so using 'r' or 'rb' to open might only solves part of the issue.

Comment: Is this still the right approach, even with six or 2to3 and other libraries? I just see how old this answer is.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: While the code in my original answer works I meanwhile release a small package at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csv342 that provides a Python 3 like interface for Python 2. So independent of your Python version you can simply do an

```
import csv342 as csv
import io
with io.open('some.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|'):
        print(row)
```

**Original answer**: Here's a solution that even with Python 2 actually decodes the text to Unicode strings and consequently works with encodings other than UTF-8.

The code below defines a function `csv_rows()` that returns the contents of a file as sequence of lists. Example usage:

```py
for row in csv_rows('some.csv', encoding='iso-8859-15', delimiter='|'):
    print(row)
```

Here are the two variants for `csv_rows()`: one for Python 3+ and another for Python 2.6+. During runtime it automatically picks the proper variant. `UTF8Recoder` and `UnicodeReader` are verbatim copies of the  [examples in the Python 2.7 library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

```py
import csv
import io
import sys


if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    # Python 3 variant.
    def csv_rows(csv_path, encoding, **keywords):
        with io.open(csv_path, 'r', newline='', encoding=encoding) as csv_file:
            for row in csv.reader(csv_file, **keywords):
                yield row

else:
    # Python 2 variant.
    import codecs

    class UTF8Recoder:
        """
        Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8
        """
        def __init__(self, f, encoding):
            self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")


    class UnicodeReader:
        """
        A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
        which is encoded in the given encoding.
        """

        def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
            f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
            self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

        def next(self):
            row = self.reader.next()
            return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]

        def __iter__(self):
            return self


    def csv_rows(csv_path, encoding, **kwds):
        with io.open(csv_path, 'rb') as csv_file:
            for row in UnicodeReader(csv_file, encoding=encoding, **kwds):
                yield row
```

Answer (score 0):

Old Question I know, but I was looking on how to do this. Just in case someone comes over this and might find it useful.

This is how i solved mine, thanks Lennart Regebro for the hint. :

```
if sys.version > '3':
       rd = csv.reader(open(input_file, 'r', newline='',
       encoding='iso8859-1'), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
else:
       rd = csv.reader(open(input_file, 'rb'), delimiter=';',
       quotechar='"')
```

then do what you need to do:

```
for row in rd:
       ......
```