# Text file converted to CSV using Python is different than converting with Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a program that parses a huge file of data output from an eye tracker. The raw file comes to me in text format, but I need a CSV file to do data analysis on.

What I had been doing is opening the text file in Excel, saving it as a .csv file, and then running it through my parser. That works fine, but it's laborious, so I want to create a piece of code to run at the beginning of my parser: which takes the raw text file, turns it into a CSV file, and then runs the parser on the just-made CSV file.

The code I am attempting to use is as follows and modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220412/convert-tab-delimited-txt-file-into-a-csv-file-using-python/1909742):

```
txt_file = subjectNum + ".asc"
csv_file = "subject_" + subjectNum + ".csv"
in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w'))
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

This generates a file just fine, but the parser then fails to process it the same way as it does the "manually-generated" files that I get when doing the conversion through Excel. The parser does create the files, but they are empty.

Also, my source text file is 17.8mb. When I convert it into CSV using Excel, the resulting file is 16mb and contains 237,218 rows. When I use the code above to convert the text file into CSV, the resulting file is 17.8mb and 236,104 rows.

It seems like I am missing something in the code above that happens when I convert manually with Excel.

Comment: could you post some of the file you are using for input and your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the file after writing to make sure it's written to disk entirely.

Also, you should always open the file in binary mode (Python 2) (or in `newline=""` mode (Python 3)).

```
with open(txt_file, "rb") as infile, open(csv_file, 'wb') as outfile:
    in_txt = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = '\t')
    out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
    out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```