# How can I convert .txt to .csv in Python?

Tags: python, json, file, csv, converters

I have a text file that's content is like bellow(I think it's a JSON object):

```
{"t":[1322352000,1322438400] , "o":[123,123], "h":[123,123], "l":[123,123], "c":[123,123]}
```

The problem is, I don't know the number of elements in each array, but they are equal as they are stock data.  I like to make a `.csv` file that each array will fill one column of it. But have no idea and experience to doing that!

How may I approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: Try Convertio? That might help. It's an online tool that converts txt to csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert tab-delimited txt file into a csv file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220412/convert-tab-delimited-txt-file-into-a-csv-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas data frame to convert your file:

```
import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_json('/path/to/infile.json')
df = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1322352000,1322438400] , "o":[123,123], "h":[123,123], "l":[123,123], "c":[123,123]})
df.to_csv('/path/to/outfile.csv', sep=",")
```