# Python skips line when printing to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create .csv file.

For some reason it skips line before printing entry.

Here is the output

[image]

But here is what I need

[image]

Below is code. Apparently `if line != "":` doesn't work

```
import csv

#-----------------------------------
def csv_writer(data,path):
    """
    Write data to a CSV file path
    """
    with open(path, "w") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in data:
            if line != "":
                writer.writerow(line)

#-----------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ["first_name,last_name,city".split(","),
            "Tyrese,Hirthe,Strackeport".split(","),
            "Jules,Dicki,Lake Nickolasville".split(","),
            "Dedric,Medhurst,Stiedemannberg".split(",")
            ]
    path = "output.csv"
    csv_writer(data,path)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some python versions (on windows) have an issue with that `with open(path, "w") as csv_file:`. A [spurious carriage return char is inserted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3), creating a blank line after each line.

You have to add `newline=""` as stated in the documentation. Python 3:

```
with open(path, "w",newline="") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

As for python 2:

```
with open(path, "wb") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

see also:

- [portable way to write csv file in python 2 or python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808284/portable-way-to-write-csv-file-in-python-2-or-python-3)
- [csv writer expected byte like and space between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892463/csv-writer-expected-byte-like-and-space-between-rows)

(note that latest Python versions on Windows don't need this anymore, but the documentation continues to state it)

Comment: the issue is specific to windows and is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3)

Answer (score 2):

When you open the file you need to pass the keyword argument newline with a blank string. This will prevent the newlines being added between rows. Your function should be:

```
def csv_writer(data,path):
    """
    Write data to a CSV file path
    """
    with open(path, "w", newline = '') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in data:
            if line:
                writer.writerow(line)
```

Note that this is only an issue on Windows.