# Python csv cutting off parts of column

Tags: python, csv

I am running into this weird issue.

I Should also mentioned this worked in the past, so I am also thinking maybe something wrong with the .csv or the specific line itself.

A quick break down. I have a script that pulls data from a .csv file of CVE (vulnerability) data. It then uses the cvss module to rescore the findings where we use the output as a way to measure priority of patching and urgency.

(this script is a temporary fix until we implement new tooling)

Here is where it messes up. Here is what my ingest file output looks like right now.

```
Vulnerability Title,Plugin ID,Original CVSS Score,Default Vector,Original Severity,AWS Score,AWS Vector,AWS Severity,Hosts,Host Type,Percentage Impacted
Cisco IOS IKEv1 Packet Handling Remote Information Disclosure (cisco-sa-20160916-ikev1) (BENIGNCERTAIN),NES-93736,4.6,CVSS2#AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N,,,AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N,,26,26,
Cisco IOS Software TCP Memory Leak DoS (cisco-sa-20150325-tcpleak),NES-82568,4.9,CVSS2#AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:C,,,AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:C,,30,26,
RHEL 5 / 6 / 7 : nss and nss-util (RHSA-2016:2779),NES-94912,4.2,CVSS2#AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:F/RL:OF/RC:ND,,,AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:F/RL:OF/RC:ND,,5112,23,
```

Here is the output after my script (which is attached bellow)

```
Vulnerability Title,Plugin ID,Original CVSS Score,Default Vector,Original Severity,AWS Score,AWS Vector,AWS Severity,Hosts,Host Type,Percentage Impacted
ium,4.6,AV:A/AC:H/Au:M/C:P/I:N/A:P/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H,Medium,26,26,0.2524271844660194
Cisco IOS Software TCP Memory Leak DoS (cisco-sa-20150325-tcpleak),NES-82568,4.9,CVSS2#AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:C,Medium,4.9,AV:A/AC:H/Au:M/C:N/I:N/A:C/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H,Medium,30,26,0.2912621359223301
RHEL 5 / 6 / 7 : nss and nss-util (RHSA-2016:2779),NES-94912,4.2,CVSS2#AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:F/RL:OF/RC:ND,Medium,4.2,AV:A/AC:H/Au:M/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:F/RL:OF/RC:ND/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H,Medium,5112,23,0.615458704550927
```

To explain it a little further, Line 1 starts with 'ium' which is a cutoff of the word Medium which comes from the bottom part of my script at line 128 (the part that says #ORIGINAL SCORE). It should say Medium. So basically, if you look at like 2 of my input, and compare to output, its cutting out this entire line, and adding only half of the word that the script is trying to add. I thought maybe it was because of all the brackers or something, but I am not sure.

```
Cisco IOS IKEv1 Packet Handling Remote Information Disclosure (cisco-sa-20160916-ikev1) (BENIGNCERTAIN),NES-93736,4.6,CVSS2#AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N,
```

Here is the script that is performing this funciton. Its a bit ugly I know, and improvement suggestions are welcomed, but finding out why its messing up my file is my priority right now. I have thought about switching to pandas but that will take a bit of time because I have never used it at all so have no idea how to do this yet.

```
def rescore_function():
#headers
    print 'Starting Rescore'
    csv_in = open('/tmp/rescore_test.csv', 'rb')
    csv_out = open('/tmp/rescored_vulnerabilities.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    reader = csv.reader(csv_in)
    headers = next(reader, None)
    if headers:
        writer.writerow(headers)

    print 'Creating Target Distrobution'
    for row in csv.reader(csv_in):
    #This is a terrible way of setting up the percentage of hosts impacted for target distrobution. Its ugly and horrible. Host count defines the host impacted, host_type identifies what kind of host it is. Such as Alinux, Rhel5, or Cisco IOS
        host_count = float(row[8])
        host_type = float(row[9])
        alinux_impact = host_count / ALINUX_HOST
        cisco_impact = host_count / CISCO_COUNT
        juniper_impact = host_count / JUNIPER_COUNT
        citrix_impact = host_count / CITRIX_COUNT        
        all_linux= host_count / LINUX_TOTAL
        print 'math set'

#The reason for vul_id is 3 lists combined is simple. alinux_impact NEEDS to be 24, cisco NEEDs to be 26, juniper NEEDS to match 27, because vul_id is the softwares 'vulnerability ID type
#range falls into all_linux. So fillvalue=vul_os[-1]  means if its not 24,26,27, it is "all_linux" which means it compares it to the All linux number.       
        vul_id = [24, 26, 27, 25] + range(24) + range(28,101)
        vul_os = [alinux_impact, cisco_impact, juniper_impact, all_linux]

        append_file = open('/tmp/rescored_vulnerabilities.csv', 'ab')
        append_write = csv.writer(append_file)

#Does the for loop with the fillvalue as mentioned above. Basically Y is the host type (linux, Cisco IOS, etc) and X is the vulnerability type. So it runs through and figures out the TD and rescore methods.
#X equals the percetange of impacted, so the Metric will be based on amount/percentage of X impacted and does a regex search and replace based on that using the CVSS calculations.
        print vul_id
        print vul_os
        for x,y in izip_longest(vul_os, vul_id, fillvalue=vul_os[-1]):
            print x,y
            print host_type
     #VECTOR REGEXP, host_type is which OS/Device type. 23 = RHEL5, 24 = Alinux, 26 = Cisco, 27 = Juniper   
            if host_type == y:
                row[10] = x
                if  x <= 0.25:
                    AC_Metric = 'A:C/CDP:L/TD:L/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    AP_Metric = 'A:P/CDP:L/TD:L/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    AN_Metric = 'A:N/CDP:L/TD:L/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCUC_Metric = 'RC:UC/CDP:L/TD:L/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCUR_Metric = 'RC:UR/CDP:L/TD:L/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCC_Metric = 'RC:C/CDP:L/TD:L/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCND_Metric = 'RC:ND/CDP:L/TD:L/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                elif 0.26 <= x <= 0.75:
                    AC_Metric = 'A:C/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    AP_Metric = 'A:P/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    AN_Metric = 'A:N/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCUC_Metric = 'RC:UC/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCUR_Metric = 'RC:UR/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCC_Metric = 'RC:C/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCND_Metric = 'RC:ND/CDP:L/TD:M/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                else:
                    AC_Metric = 'A:C/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    AP_Metric = 'A:P/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    AN_Metric = 'A:N/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCUC_Metric = 'RC:UC/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCUR_Metric = 'RC:UR/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCC_Metric = 'RC:C/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'
                    RCND_Metric = 'RC:ND/CDP:L/TD:H/CR:H/IR:H/AR:H'


                text = row[6]
                text = re.sub(r'AV:N','AV:A',text)
                text = re.sub(r'AC:L','AC:H',text)
                text = re.sub(r'AC:M','AC:H',text)
                text = re.sub(r'Au:N','Au:M',text)
                text = re.sub(r'Au:S','Au:M',text)
                text = re.sub(r'A:C$',AC_Metric,text)
                text = re.sub(r'A:P$',AP_Metric,text)
                text = re.sub(r'A:N$',AP_Metric,text)
                text = re.sub(r'RC:UC',RCUC_Metric,text)
                text = re.sub(r'RC:UR',RCUR_Metric,text)
                text = re.sub(r'RC:C',RCC_Metric,text)
                text = re.sub(r'RC:ND',RCND_Metric,text)
                row[6] = text
    #NEW SCORE, uses CVSS module to take the previous vector and find out the the numbered score. It then uses that number to define the severity word.
                try:
                    vector = row[6]
                    c = CVSS2(vector)
                    row[5] = c.scores()[2]
                    vul_score = row[5]
                    if 0 <= vul_score <= 3.9:
                        vuln_word = 'Low'
                    elif 4.0 <= vul_score <=6.9:
                        vuln_word = 'Medium'
                    elif 7.0 <= vul_score <= 9.9:
                        vuln_word = 'High'
                    else:
                        vuln_word = 'Critical'
                    row[7] = vuln_word
                except CVSS2MalformedError:
                    rescored_success = False
                    pass
    #ORIGINAL SCORE, does the same as above for the original vector since NESSUS does not provide the Severity "word". This only finds the word, not the number value.
                default_score = float(row[2])
                if 0 <= default_score <= 3.9:
                    default_severity = 'Low'
                elif 4.0 <= default_score <=6.9:
                    default_severity = 'Medium'
                elif 7.0 <= default_score <= 9.9:
                    default_severity = 'High'
                else:
                    default_severity = 'Critical'
                row[4] = default_severity
                append_write.writerow(row)
```

Comment: actually r or rb is OK in python 2. It's when writing that most python 2 versions (but the lastest release) needs `"wb"` or it inserts blank lines (on windows).

Comment: it's a bug, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808284/portable-way-to-write-csv-file-in-python-2-or-python-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite big so hard to reproduce, but I suspect that something is fishy with the write file handles and all the buffering going on/concurrent buffered file access in write mode. Quite a mess

1. first you're opening / truncating with `csv_out = open('/tmp/rescored_vulnerabilities.csv', 'wb')`
2. you write the header
3. for *each iteration*, whereas the aforementioned handle isn't closed, you open the file in *append* mode:
   `append_file = open('/tmp/rescored_vulnerabilities.csv', 'ab')`
4. you don't close `append_file` either !

I'd advise this:

- first truncated open is ok
- remove `append_file = open('/tmp/rescored_vulnerabilities.csv', 'ab')`
- replace `append_write` by `write` (it will work, `write` points on the same file and is still open)
- don't forget to `close` `csv_out` in the end (or put all the code in a `with open(...) as csv_out:` block

Note that this issue is Un*x only. On Windows filesystems, it would throw an exception right away because file cannot be opened twice in write mode (and sometimes it's just as well).

Comment: Ah, yeah it was that append file. I removed that and switched it to just use the original writer and that fixed everything. Thank you so much for the help! And I do close the file write file a little later int he script when its done, but I will fix all that as well.

Comment: that's great! I didn't see what else it could be.