# Python - Use key from nested csv as main key

Tags: python, json, csv

Apologies for the poorly worded title.

Basically, I have a csv file where rows look like this:

```
1234567, Install X Software on Y Machine, ServiceTicket,"{'id': 47, 'name': 'SERVICE BOARD', '_info': {'board_href': 'https://MY-URl'}}","{'id': 897, 'name': 'Completed', '_info': {'status_href': 'https://MY-URl'}}...
```

The first nested list's key name is 'board' and the second is 'status'. I am trying to format this such that the nested 'name' key is used in place of 'board' and 'status.' I would like it to be formatted like this:

```
1234567, Install X Software on Y Machine, ServiceTicket, SERVICE BOARD, Completed
```

I am completely lost on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is my code for retrieving .json data from a get request and converting it to .csv:

```
data = requests.get(url=TICKET_URL, headers=HEADER_AUTH) ### Get data from
data = data.json()
count = 0;
csvData = open("test.csv", "w")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvData)
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        for item in data:
            if count == 0:
                header = item.keys()
                csvWriter.writerow(header)
                count += 1
            csvWriter.writerow(item.values())
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
csvData.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you add info how data looks like?

Comment: Which data? I have in here how a row in the csv file looks like, and there are hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't so good solution, but should works. Also, you can look at itemgeter

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('foo1', 'foo2'))
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in data:
        record = []
        for item in i.values():
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                record.append(item['name'])
            else:
                record.append(item)
        writer.writerow(record)
```

Comment: careful when opening csv files for writing under windows with infamous blank lines (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808284/portable-way-to-write-csv-file-in-python-2-or-python-3)

Comment: Lol! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired format by flattening the json file prior to converting it to csv and then deleting unwanted keys. Not an ideal answer but it works.